# How can make an ios application dynamically update function module with framework on ios8?

Tags: ios, frameworks

Now I have an iOS app which has lots of function modules , so I think how to make it supporting dynamically update? I have try it like this: Making an framework which includes function module, and then put the framework into the app's sandbox(document directory), and then dynamically load this framework from the sandbox. Of course, if you put that framework on server and download it to your app, in this way it looks like dynamically update.

Does Apple support this way?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not real sure what you're asking, but Apple does not allow applications to download executable code, and there's no means to create a dynamically linked library.

Comment: where do you know that Apple does not allow applications to download executable code? In fact，my test process as follows:

Comment: NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentDirectory =  [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *libName = @"ShareFramework.framework”; NSString *destLibPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:libName];
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:destLibPath];
  Class ShareViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"ShareViewController");

    UIViewController *svc = [ShareViewControllerClass new];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];

Comment: It's fairly well documented as a violation of the app store guidelines.